# React Context Provider not updating Class.contextType

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

My app uses the React Context Provider to pass down a user profile. In my App component, I have my state defined as:

```
interface IState {
  authUser: any;
  userProfile: IProfile;
  roles: string[];
}
```

Within my componentDidMount method, I call out to three different API's using fetch. The results then call setState for the respective entries.
The render part of my App is:

```
<AuthenticationContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Navigation />
            <Switch>
/* Other routes removed for brevity */
              <Route exact={true} path={routes.HOME} component={Home} />
            </Switch>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </AuthenticationContext.Provider>
```

Within the Home component, I'm using the static Class.contextType entry as so:

```
public static contextType = AuthenticationContext;
public context!: React.ContextType<typeof AuthenticationContext>;
```

Then within the componentDidMount method, I'm calling another API with entries from the this.context.userProfile object.

I added console log statements to trace through the lifecycle. When I perform a reload of the page, I get this:

```
Calling /api/profiles/getAdminStatus/7J4OwwnmQ1fMhavSLeLkDkKe9Kl2
Calling getProfile within App
Calling /api/profiles/7J4OwwnmQ1fMhavSLeLkDkKe9Kl2 within getProfile
Calling /api/profiles/7J4OwwnmQ1fMhavSLeLkDkKe9Kl2 within getLookingFor
Calling loadProfiles
Calling getFilterResults with Userid: 
Calling /api/search
About to setState in getProfile within App: UserId: 7J4OwwnmQ1fMhavSLeLkDkKe9Kl2
```

The getFilterResults is showing a blank Userid entry. However, if I browse to another page and then come back to this page, I get these results:

```
Calling /api/profiles/7J4OwwnmQ1fMhavSLeLkDkKe9Kl2 within getLookingFor
Calling loadProfiles
Calling getFilterResults with Userid: 7J4OwwnmQ1fMhavSLeLkDkKe9Kl2
Calling /api/search
```

Based on the messages, I'm certain that the problem is the initial calls to get the current user aren't returning before the Home component loads. However, I don't understand why the component isn't rerendering when the setState is happening.
I added the Consumer Component around the contents of the home page, but that didn't help.

I came up with an idea of pushing the list of results and method up to the Context as well so that I could avoid using the static contextType, but that seems hackish to me.

Any thoughts on what I might have done wrong???

*****Edit*****
This is the Home component:

```
interface IHomeComponentState {
  profiles: IProfileShort[];
  hasMore: boolean;
  error: boolean;
  isLoading: boolean;
}
class HomeComponent extends React.Component<any, IHomeComponentState> {
  public static contextType = AuthenticationContext;
  public _isMounted = false;
  public context!: React.ContextType<typeof AuthenticationContext>;
  private currentPage: number = 0;

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      profiles: [],
      hasMore: true,
      error: false,
      isLoading: false,
    };
    this.loadProfiles.bind(this);

    window.onscroll = () => {
      if (this.state.error || this.state.isLoading || !this.state.hasMore) {
        return;
      }

      if (
        window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop ===
        document.documentElement.offsetHeight
      ) {
        this.loadProfiles();
      }
    };
  }

  public loadProfiles() {
    if (this.context) {
      const value = this.context;
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-console
      console.log(
        'Calling getFilterResults with Userid: ' + value.userProfile.userId,
      );

      getFilterResults(
        value.userProfile.gender,
        value.userProfile.lookingForGender,
        value.userProfile.minAge,
        value.userProfile.maxAge,
        value.userProfile.connectionType,
        value.userProfile.dateOfBirth,
        this.currentPage,
      )
        .then(newProfiles => {
          this.setState(
            {
              profiles: [...this.state.profiles, ...newProfiles],
            },
            () => {
              this.currentPage = this.currentPage + 1;
            },
          );
        })
        .catch();
    }
  }

  public componentDidMount() {
    // tslint:disable-next-line: no-console
    console.log('Calling loadProfiles');
    this.loadProfiles();
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <Grid container justify="center" direction="column" alignContent="center">
        <Paper>
          <Grid container item spacing={40} style={{ maxWidth: '840px' }}>
            {this.state.profiles.map(profile => (
              <Grid
                key={profile.userId}
                item
                sm={6}
                style={{ maxWidth: '200px' }}
              >
                <Link
                  to={`/profile/${profile.userId}`}
                  style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}
                >
                  <ProfileCard
                    key={profile.userId}
                    name={profile.name}
                    picUrl={profile.picUrl}
                    userId={profile.userId}
                    age={profile.age}
                    orientation="horizontal"
                    location={profile.location}
                  />
                </Link>
              </Grid>
            ))}
          </Grid>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

const authCondition = (authUser: any) => !!authUser;

export const Home = withAuthorization(authCondition)(HomeComponent);
```

Also, my react and react-dom versions are both 16.8.6.

Comment: everything happens in your Home component? if so can you post that component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research, it appears that the proper way to handle this is to actually add methods within the Context object that modifies the state within the App (or whichever component houses the Context.Provider object.